# Getting tiles from WMTS document using GeoTools?

Tags: java, geotools, wmts

I was wondering if there is a library which I can use to retrieve TileMatrix/Tile information from a WMTS Capabilities document. I have been trying to use geotools but it seems as though it does not support WMTS (just WMS).

Comment: have you seen http://lists.refractions.net/pipermail/udig-devel/2012-July/021988.html?

Comment: @iant Thanks for the link. Tried this out but could not get it to work. Now exploring the use of XMLBeans to parse data from a wmts capabilities document.

Comment: There is some (initial) support for WMTS in owslib - python, but possibly you could use it as a model or via Jython?

Comment: @BradHards Thanks for that! Seems quite useful, although I went down another route, I will give this a try  :)

Comment: Could you add your solution as an Answer (below) and close this out?

Comment: Hi Brad, I shall do so as soon as i give it a try, it might not be for a week or so though, unless you meant what route I chose right now ?

Comment: Use gdal_translate. Read from (almost) every popular file format or web services, and write to (almost) every popular format. I had successfully use it to read from WMS/WMTS and write to mbtiles. No programming required.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) now has a [WMTS module](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/wmts/wmts.html) that will handle this (and more) for you:

> The client code is fairly slick in that it takes care of version
>   negotiation (inheriting functionalities from AbstractOpenWebService),
>   and even a few server specific wrinkles for you.